# Constructing a circle with center belonging to a line, tangent to another line and passing through a point

Tags: geometric-construction

Given: two nonparallel lines $a$ and $b$ and point $P$.

Construct: a circle whose center belongs to $a$, passes through $P$ and is tangent to $b$.

[image]

Comment: This isn't always possible so...

Comment: Observe that the center of the circle must be in the parabola with focus $P$ and directrix $b$. Then [intersect the parabola with the line $a$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/793125/713897).

Comment: @conditionalMethod Yes, this solves it! I did not at all notice the parabola. Turned out it is more complicated than I thought. I was thinking that I'm simply missing something elementary. Please paste your comment as an answer, so I can mark it as answered. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @conditionalMethod for pointing me to the parabola idea. One of the answers in the linked question ([this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/838364/730102)) gave me idea how to solve the problem even more simply:

[image]

1. Extend $a$ and $b$ until they intersect in $O$.
2. Build helper circle with center $A$ anywhere on $a$ and tangent to $b$.
3. Draw line through $P$ and $O$, intersecting the helper circle in $B$ and $C$.
4. Draw line parallel to $AB$ through $P$, intersecting $a$ in $Q$. This is the center of the one solution.
5. Draw line parallel to $AC$ through $P$, intersecting $a$ in $R$. This is the center of the other solution.